# Django apache: admin fields are not updated on apache server

Tags: django, apache

I have an django app that is nice working on the django's dev server. But it is not working correctly on the appache server. There are no new fields in the admin page after they had been added to the model. They are appear only if to run the app on the Django's dev server. 
I have tried to solve it with appache httpd settings and to show the static files path of admin/static, but it is no effect.
Please help to solve this issue.
My appache django.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /static /usr/local/mainproject/mysite/mysite/static/
Alias /static/admin /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-    packages/django/contrib/admin/static/
Alias /media/admin /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/

<Directory /usr/local/mainproject/mysite/mysite/static/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/usr/local/mainproject/mysite:/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/mainproject/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=mysite

<Directory /usr/local/mainproject/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted 
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My **admin.py**

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from testres.models import Task, Issue, Result

 class IssueInline(admin.StackedInline):
     model = Issue

 class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fieldsets = [
         (None,  {'fields':['task_name']}),
         ('Description', {'fields':['task_description']}),
 #       ('Date information', {'fields': ['task_pub_date']}),
         ('Owners', {'fields':['task_owner']}),
     ]
     inlines = [IssueInline]

 class IssueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fieldsets = [
         (None,  {'fields':['issue_name']}),
         ('Severity', {'fields':['issue_severity']}),
         ('Type', {'fields':['issue_type']}),
         ('Task', {'fields': ['task']}),
         ('Description', {'fields': ['issue_description']}),
     ]

 class ResultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fieldsets = [
         ('Teacher Name',  {'fields':['teacher_name']}),
         ('Student Name', {'fields':['student_name']}),
         ('Task', {'fields': ['task']}),
         ('English level', {'fields':['english_level']}),
         ('Comment to result', {'fields': ['result_comment']}),
         ('Total Results', {'fields': ['total_result']}),
         ('Result Resolution', {'fields': ['result_resolution']}),

     ]


 admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
 admin.site.register(Issue, IssueAdmin)
 admin.site.register(Result, ResultAdmin)
```

My **models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)            # name of the task
    task_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)    # description of the task
    task_pub_date = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)       # date of publication
    task_owner = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.task_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_task', kwargs={'task_id': self.id})



class Issue(models.Model):
    issue_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Issue severity field
    CRITICAL = 'CRT'
    BLOCKER = 'BLC'
    MAJOR = 'MJR'
    AVERAGE = 'AVG'
    MINOR = 'MIN'
    ISSUE_SEVERITY_CHOICES = (
        (CRITICAL, 'Critical'),
        (BLOCKER, 'Blocker'),
        (MAJOR, 'Major'),
        (AVERAGE, 'Average'),
        (MINOR, 'Minor'),
    )
    issue_severity = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ISSUE_SEVERITY_CHOICES, default=AVERAGE)
    #Issue type field
    SPEC = 'SPC'
    HIGHPRIORITY = 'HGH'
    NOTTRIVIAL = 'NTR'
    ALLOTHER = 'ALL'
    ISSUE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (SPEC, 'Дефекты на несоответствие со спецификацией'),
        (HIGHPRIORITY, 'Дефекты 1-го и 2-го приоритета'),
        (NOTTRIVIAL, 'Нетривиальные дефекты'),
        (ALLOTHER, 'Остальные дефекты'),
    )
    issue_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ISSUE_TYPE_CHOICES, default=ALLOTHER)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    issue_description = models.TextField(max_length=3000, default='empty')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.issue_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_issue', kwargs={'issue_id': self.id})


class Result(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    result_pub_date = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total_result = models.FloatField(default=0)
    english_level_choices =(
        ('1','elementary'),
        ('2','pre-intermediate'),
        ('3','intermediate'),
        ('4','upper-intermediate'),
        ('5','русскоязычное задание'),
    )
    english_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=english_level_choices, default='5')
    result_comment = models.TextField(max_length=3000, default='empty')
    RESULT_RESOLUTION_CHOICES = (
        ('Reject', 'Rejected'),
        ('Accept', 'Accepted'),
    )
    result_resolution = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=RESULT_RESOLUTION_CHOICES, default='Reject')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.student_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_result', kwargs={'result_id': self.id})
```

My **settings.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from unipath import Path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3kd1=9yyyqcsl2%f(9^ed6ye917nhc5!vq8+gxiu)s4-r+)3oq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'testres',
    'django_python3_ldap',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_static_jquery',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'




# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
# django.db.backends.mysql - engine for old version

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql_cymysql',
        'NAME': 'testresult',
        'USER': 'trdbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'qwe123QWE',
        'HOST': 'localhost',        
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child('static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        PROJECT_DIR.child('static'),
)

# Login info
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/loggedin/'

# LDAP INSTALLATION
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# The URL of the LDAP server.
LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldap://ldap.testserver.corp:389"

# Initiate TLS on connection.
LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = False

# The LDAP search base for looking up users.
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=testserver,DC=testserver,DC=corp"

# The LDAP class that represents a user. ??????
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "user"

#Data for user model collected from LDAP account

LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

# A tuple of django model fields used to uniquely identify a user.???????
LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)

# Path to a callable that takes a dict of {model_field_name: value},???????
# returning a dict of clean model data.
# Use this to customize how data loaded from LDAP is saved to the User model.
LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"

# Path to a callable that takes a user model and a dict of {ldap_field_name: [value]},???????
# and saves any additional user relationships based on the LDAP data.
# Use this to customize how data loaded from LDAP is saved to User model relations.
# For customizing non-related User model fields, use LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA.
LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"

# Path to a callable that takes a dict of {ldap_field_name: value},???????
# returning a list of [ldap_search_filter]. The search filters will then be AND'd
# together when creating the final search filter.
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_search_filters"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"

LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = 'testserver'

# The LDAP username and password of a user for authenticating the `ldap_sync_users`
# management command. Set to None if you allow anonymous queries.
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = 'CN=Test Link,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Users,OU=testserver,DC=testserver,DC=corp'
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = 'testpass'

#SMTP settings
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.testserver.corp'
#EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
#EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

My **urls.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home' ),
    url(r'^testres/', include('testres.urls', namespace="testres")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # user auth urls
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^loggedin/$', views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),

]

if settings.DEBUG == True:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My **wsgi.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/mainproject/mysite')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/mainproject')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/mainproject/mysite')
sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.3/'
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/MySQLdb')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The **solution** had beed found:
The issue is in different Apache interfaces. 
I used **apachectl restart** but this one do not restart .py files.
**httpd -k restart** restarts deamon and fix this issue

Comment: What exactly is the problem? you get a not found page???

Comment: No i am getting everything ok, all page is fine but there are no new field that i have added to the app model. I have done all migrations and there is new field on this app on Django's default dev server.

Comment: maybe the problem is that you didn't do the migration, `$ python manage.py makemigrations` and after that `$ python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Did you remember to restart Apache after updating the code in production?

Comment: As I added in priveous comment, that i have done all this steps, and data is in database. It is working fine on the devs server. Yes i have done apache restart many times after it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an apache configuration problem, this is my apache configuration:

```
#set wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/sciblog:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup example.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sciblog/sciblog/wsgi.py process-group=example.com
#set public directories for apache
Alias /img/ /var/www/sciblog/img/
Alias /static/ /var/www/sciblog/blog/static/
<Directory /var/www/sciblog/blog/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/sciblog/img>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/sciblog/sciblog>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

The admin files are added to the project. Also I didn't put vitualhost tags. Please take a look at this repository: [sciblog](https://github.com/hoaphumanoid/sciblog)

Comment: Thanks, but i have tried different configs and it has no effect. It seems like admin module has no connect with updated database structure